# Can directing to a specific site be avoided in any way using servlets?

Tags: java, html, web-services, servlets

Is it possible to block directing to a specific site using servlets. For example, when yahoo.com is typed in url box, the network connection should turn off, whereas when you type some other website url, say, google.com, the network connection should remain intact. (maybe by working on ip filters??)

Comment: Show the codes which you have worked for servlets

Comment: What does your question have to do with servlets? Servlets execute on a server. They're not a browser plugin that could block some URLs. Why would a servlet, deployed at yourcompany.com, be aware of a user typing yahoo.com in his browser?

Answer (score 0):

Servlets would not be a right choice for this kind of requirement.

Servlets are deployed at server and will work only when request is submitted to them from the browser. Typing URL in the browser would not allow servlet to react.

You can install any kind of Proxy at your local network and block the websites accordingly.

In case, if you are talking about any browser request that is calling your servlet and your servlet is redirect the request to any of the websites like Yahoo, Google etc... then the following procedure might work for you.

1. Maintain a list of blocked websites in a list
2. Check for the requested website in the request object
3. If the requested website is not in the list then you can allow the redirect
4. Else, you can forward to a page where website blocked message is displayed

Hope this answers your question.

Please let me know if you have any further questions.